# Can a Dell U2515H monitor bought in Europe be plugged in in America?

Tags: display, power

I have a Dell U2515H monitor which I'd like to bring to the U.S. Is it possible to plug it into the power socket there? (I wasn't able to read 110/220 V or anything like that on the back).

Comment: What type of plug does it have?  What is printed on the display?  Honestly, I would call Dell and ask them this question, since the model number isn't enough to do research on.

Comment: can be found in 30s on a search engine... Yes as long as you replace the plug connector

Comment: @A.B Your source?

Comment: Hum ok tried in English and not that easy. here's the reference (I don't know in what language depending on who queries): http://www.dell.com/cg/entreprise/p/dell-u2515h-monitor/pd#TechSpec (look for "240 V" and see 100 (V) just before as well as 60 Hz after). Note that /cg/ is actually Congo. Nowadays anything sold internationally that supports 240v (Europe) also supports 110v